# How to append Google Analytics code in head using JS

Tags: javascript, append, appendchild

I am trying to append Google Analytics Script code within head when the UserAgent is not bot(googlebot).

What I am trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var CheckUA = agent.match(/Googlebot/i);

if(!CheckUA) {
       var scriptTagAnalytics = "***MY GA script CODE***"; 
       document.head.prepend(scriptTagAnalytics);
}
</script>
```

My Google Analytics Code is:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789-1">
</script>
<script>
    function gtag(){
        dataLayer.push(arguments)
    }
    window.dataLayer=window.dataLayer||[],
    gtag("js",new Date),
    gtag("config","UA-123456789-1");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it and it is reflecting in Google Analytics. The only thing is the source code will be visible.

```
 if(!CheckUA) {
  (function() {
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var myScript = document.createElement('script');
  myScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-123456789-1');
  myScript.onload = function() {
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag() { dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    console.log('window.dataLayer Executed', window.dataLayer)
    gtag('config', 'UA-123456789-1');
  }
  head.insertBefore(myScript, head.children[1]);
})();
```